# `/usr/bin/cd` is not working in mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I was checking the path of `cd` command in macOS terminal using `which cd`, I got `/usr/bin/cd`, so whenever I use this full path to execute `cd` it doesn't work as expected.

So here are some examples.

1. Any valid path here root(`/`) as arg.

   `/usr/bin/cd /` -> doesn't change dir as specified
2. Any invalid path here (kjfd) as arg.

   `/usr/bin/cd kjfd` -> `/usr/bin/cd: line 4: cd: kjfd: No such file or directory`

So, I really don't understand why `cd` with complete path address(`/usr/bin/cd /`) is not working while other commands like `bin/echo` do work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working. `/usr/bin/cd` changes *its own* working directory. Then it exits.

A process can change only its own working directory, not the working directory of some other process. No external tool can change the working directory of your current shell (exceptions: debuggers and such), so normally you use the `cd` *builtin* which is a part of the shell itself. It's the shell who changes its own working directory, `/usr/bin/cd` cannot do this for the shell.

There is this question [*What is the point of the `cd` external command?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/108618) This is from [one of the answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/50060/108618) there:

> It serves primarily as making sure the POSIX tool-chest is available both inside and outside a shell […]
>
> For `cd`, that is not tremendously useful but note that `cd` changes directories but has other side effects: it returns an exit status that helps determine whether you're able to `chdir()` to that directory or not, and outputs a useful error message explaining why you can't `chdir()` when you can't.

`which cd` is not aware of shell builtins. Again you need the shell itself to tell what sole `cd` really is. E.g. in Bash there is the `type` builtin:

```
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

Comment: `The point is any executable changes its own working directory (if ever)`, I really didn't get you here, could you help, please?

Comment: @codeitram Each process has its own working directory; if `cd` runs in as a separate process from the shell (which /usr/bin/cd does), when it changes directory it's changing the directory of the `cd` process, not that of the shell process. You wanted the shell process's directory to change. In order to change the shell process's directory, the change must be done *in that process* (i.e. in the shell itself), not in another process.