# Running `whatis cd` always returns "nothing appropriate" on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, man, cd

I was just playing around with the `whatis` command. For some reason, whenever I run `whatis cd`, I get `cd: nothing appropriate.` What does this mean? Why is this? It seems there is no `man` entry for `cd` either. Why is *that*?

Comment: That could mean that `cd` is not implemented as a seperate executable.  Try `man sh`, and then search for a description of the `cd` command under the **Builtins** section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`/usr/bin/cd\` is not working in mac terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/1459436/usr-bin-cd-is-not-working-in-mac-terminal)

Comment: That's not a very good duplicate of this question. Maybe it's not even a good enough duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 4):

`cd` is a builtin shell command:

> ```
> $ type cd
> cd is a shell builtin
> ```

The documentation for `cd` can be found with:

```
man builtins
```

Run it then press `/` and search for "cd".

In Bash you can also open a help page with:

```
help cd
```

Answer (score 0):

`whatis` displays one line of information from the man page of the command (the one you find in the `NAME` section).

`nothing appropriate` is displayed when no man page is found for that command.

`cd` has no man page of its own because it is not an executable but a built-in of your shell (like `shopt` or `alias` for instance)(*), hence the result you get.

(*) To make the matter a bit more complex there are plain commands such as `echo` and `printf` that are overridden by like-named (and usually upward compatible) shell built-ins, so these built-ins appear to have their own `man` page, but the man page is really for the executable (which could have slightly different parameters).